# Надо ли знать C#, чтобы начать писать под ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Или можно сразу читать книги по ASP.NET? Есть опыт в программировании (1 год на Delphi, потом был С, PHP).

Comment: Обязательно =))

Answer (score 2):

учил С, с шарпом разберешься быстро, если есть мозг :)
да и вообще, используя любые мелкомягкие технологии для веба, шарп так или иначе пригодится

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, ASP - это технология, а язык то там C#!

Comment: Простите, но нет-же:

Разработчики могут писать код для ASP.NET, используя **практически любые языки программирования, входящие в комплект .NET Framework** (C#, Visual Basic.NET и JScript.NET)

######**[список языков](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.D0.AF.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B2_.NET)**

А вообще - это facepalm :)